# How to capture customer email address in a landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud

so I have a link in my email that points to a landing page that I created in exacttarget. I want to capture the email address and save it to a data extension, I also need a date created field in the data extension. Is there anybody know how to do that?

Comment: Make sure you add some code that you have already tried when asking questions.  Some general understanding will help others answer your questions and be respectful of their time as well.

Comment: yes, I understand. but what code? its just a link in the email? what should I put?

Comment: You want to try to do as much research in advanced, and not just ask for code to complete a task.  Glad you were able to get an answer for this and get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass over a query string parameter (you can encrypt this if you like using AMPScript)
The URL will look something like http://linktolanding.com/page.aspx?qs=qwerty&email=**%%EmailAddr%%**

In your landing page you can retrieve the value by using RequestParameter()

```
%%[

SET @email = RequestParameter("email")

InsertData("Data Extension Name", "Email", @email)

]%%
```

As for creating a date created field in the Data Extension - just navigate to the Data Extension and add a new column called date created with a data type of date and check the box to use today's date as the default. That way you won't need to include a date stamp in the AMPScript function.